# Add rows in between with default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with values like this

I am using MySQL and first field is date (TIMESTAMP), second is Double

```
09:00:00 xxx
09:01:00 yyy
09:04:00 zzz
```

Would it be possible to do an insert that adds the missing rows (09:02:00, 09:03:00)? In that case what would the SQL look like?

Comment: Which is your database? What's the data type of column?

Comment: what should be second field with `09:02:00, 09:03:00?`

Comment: If the second field is NULLABLE then you can, else you will need to specify a value.

Comment: How would the SQL look for that ?

Comment: ... _Why_ are you trying to do this?  Note that there are **FAR** more than just the two values you specified logically available - seconds, and potentially some subsecond measures.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you may not need the extra rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a procedure that inserts all necessary values into a temporary table. Something like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_date_range;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_date_range(IN startdate datetime, IN enddate datetime)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TABLE tmp_date_range(a_datetime datetime primary key);

SET @date := startdate;

WHILE (@date <= enddate) DO
INSERT INTO tmp_date_range VALUES (@date);
SET @date := @date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now call it with start and end dates.

```
CALL sp_date_range('2014-03-10 14:00:00', NOW());
```

Now you have a table like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tmp_date_range;
+---------------------+
| a_date              |
+---------------------+
| 2014-03-10 14:00:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:01:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:02:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:03:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:04:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:05:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:06:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:07:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:08:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:09:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:10:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:11:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:12:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:13:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:14:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:15:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:16:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:17:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:18:00 |
| 2014-03-10 14:19:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Now you insert missing values like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_timestamp_column)
SELECT a.a_datetime
FROM tmp_date_range a
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON a.a_datetime = b.your_timestamp_column
WHERE b.your_timestamp_column IS NULL;
```

Note though, that I'm assuming that your other columns in your table are NULLable. Otherwise you'll have to specify a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly insert via query and than alter table to arrange data in date order

```
INSERT INTO tbl values('09:02:00', 'AAA'), ('09:03:00', 'BBB');
ALTER tbl ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Yeah well but assume that you have 10000 more of those?